# Cannot read property 'hexToAscii' of undefined

Tags: web3js, blockchain, error

```
deployedContract.deploy({
  data: bytecode,
  arguments: [listOfCandidates.map(name => web3.utils.hexToAscii(Rama))]
}).send({
  from: '0xfb9286cde20bbd5ed60ee3bb156f9d9938c5b151',
  gas: 1500000,
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('0.00003', 'ether')
}).then((newContractInstance) => {
  deployedContract.options.address = newContractInstance.options.address
  console.log(newContractInstance.options.address)
});

TypeError: Cannot read property 'hexToAscii' of undefined
  at deployedContract.deploy.arguments.listOfCandidates.map.name (repl:3:55)
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely using Web3 0.x, while `web3.utils.hexToAscii()` is a Web3 1.0 syntax. The equivalent for Web3 0.x would be `web3.toAscii()`.

Comment: Also: a recent web3.js release made it so the static Web3 import doesn't have the `utils` property anymore. You have to create an instance of web3 to get the utils property, which I can't tell if they're doing based on the code.